# THE PROBABLE ERROR OF A MEAN- seminal 1908 paper from Gosset (Student). Please help me to understand the first identity in Section 1

Tags: probability-distributions

I am reading the original 1908 paper "The probable error of a mean" from William Sealy Gosset (Student pseudonym) where the Student T Distribution was first derived.

On section 1 (at the end of page 2 in the [original paper](https://www.york.ac.uk/depts/maths/histstat/student.pdf)) the author starts with the following sentence:
"Samples of n individuals are drawn out of a population distributed normally, to
find an equation which shall represent the frequency of the standard deviations
of these samples.
If s be the standard deviation found from a sample x1 x2 . . . xn (all these
being measured from the mean of the population), then
$s^2=\frac{S(x_1^2)}{n}-\left(\frac{S(x_1)}{n}\right)^2=\frac{S(x_1^2)}{n}-\frac{S(x_1^2)}{n^2}-\frac{2S(x_1x_2)}{n^2}$."

The S in the formula above is not previously defined...it may represent a summation (as I guess) or the sample variance. Also it is not clear to me whether x1, x2 etc are single individuals or samples of several individuals...

You see I am pretty confused about the formula above, so I'm not able to follow the (apparently elementary) mathematical derivations in the Section 1 until I don't get this preliminary identity.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: $S(x_1)$ is what we would write $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ nowadays.  Similarly, $S(x_1^2)=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$, and (this is the tricky one) $S(x_1x_2)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=1+1}^n x_i x_j$, which we would also write as $\sum_{i<j}x_i x_j$.

Comment: Many thanks Kimchi lover. So the author of the paper is computing the sample variance about the sample mean:  $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}{n})^2}{n}$ .  In this case S(x1 x2) seems to be simply the double sum $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nx_ix_j$.  I never found this notation for summations elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you @Brian Moehring for correcting the formula.

Comment: @AndreaAndrea You're welcome (honestly, I just didn't want the question derailed by a typo).  It seems unlikely that $S(x_1x_2)$ relates to your double sum, though, unless you intend that one of $S(x_1) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ or $S(x_1^2) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$ is an incorrect interpretation of the notation.  Once we have those, we immediately find $S(x_1x_2) = \sum_{1\leq i < j \leq n} x_ix_j$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring and kimchilover   ...you are perfectly right. I had a momentary eclipse in my brain :-) Sorry, and thanks again